# Return a new value and replace it everywhere

Tags: php, html

I have a project at school with html and php and I have some problems.
I have a database, and in my html I have a button to add friends to camping.
I retrieve the value of how many friends he can add from the database, this is the code:

```
$campingNumber = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reservation where email = '$email'")->fetch();
$maxCampingPersons = (int) $campingNumber['persons_nb'] -1;
```

I am getting the max nr of persons that are allowed -1 because 1 of the persons is the leader.
 To show information about the camping I have this code:

```
<td class="even"> 
<?php echo is_null($user_account['camping']) == false ? $user_account['camping'] : 'No info'; ?> , &nbsp Camping place:&nbsp
<?php echo is_null($campingNumber['spot_nb'])==false? $campingNumber['spot_nb'] : 'No info';?>
<br/> Number of friends you can add:&nbsp 
<?php if($maxCampingPersons == -1) { echo ($maxCampingPersons) ==0 ? $maxCampingPersons : 'No info'; } 
else { echo is_null($maxCampingPersons) == false ? $maxCampingPersons : 'No info';} ?> 
</td>
```

And to add friends to camping I have this piece of code:

```
<div>
<?php if($maxCampingPersons>0) { ?>
      <p><input class="addcamping" type="button" value="Add friends to camping"   id="popup2-toggle" /></p> <?php }
 else {?>
      <p><input class="addcamping" type="button" value="Add friends to camping" id="popup2-toggle" disabled /></p> <?php }?>
<div class="popup2-overlay">
<div class="popup2">
<a href="#" class="popup2-close">X</a>
<h2 style="color: black;">Hello <?php echo $query['first_name']; ?> </h2>
<p style="color: black;">Add friends to your camping</p>
<p style="color: black;">You can add <?php echo is_null($maxCampingPersons)==false? $maxCampingPersons : '0';?>  friend/friends to your camping</p>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ ?>

<form method="post" action="addCamping.php">
<div class="popup2-form-row">

<input type="text" id="popup2-form_login" value="" name="friendEmail" placeholder="friend@fontys.nl" />
</div>

<input class="addpeople" type="submit" value="Add friend" name="addCamping"/>
</form>     

 <?php } $maxCampingPersons= $maxCampingPersons - 1; ?>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
p2 = $('.popup2-overlay')
$('#popup2-toggle').click(function() {
p2.css('display', 'block')
})
p2.click(function(event) {
e = event || window.event
if (e.target == this) {
$(p2).css('display', 'none')
}
})
$('.popup2-close').click(function() {
p2.css('display', 'none')
})
</script>
</div>
```

How can I do that after I add a friend `$maxCampingPersons` to be updated with -1 and to be updated everywhere? Because I've putted `$maxCampingPersons= $maxCampingPersons - 1` at the end of form but it's now working.

Thank you,
Alexandru

Comment: php (and javascript) cannot time travel. if you update a variable at some time X, that will not magically go back in time to change its value at time X-1.

Comment: I was afraid of this, a solution that I have in my mind was to create another table in the database for camping leader, and update that table everytime he's gonna add someone to his place. But I was thinking that maybe could have been done easier.

Comment: Just create another variable so you can use $x and then when you need to use the -1 just make $y= $x-1 or do you need it to update your database with the neg 1.

Comment: if ($maxCampingPersons == -1) { echo ($maxCampingPersons) == 0 ? $maxCampingPersons : 'No info'; } - is it me or does this part make no sense, you're checking for -1 and then checking if -1 == 0

Comment: sorry for that, that final piece of code is like this  `<?php if($maxCampingPersons < 0) { echo ($maxCampingPersons) == false ? $maxCampingPersons : 'No info'; } 
 else { echo is_null($maxCampingPersons) == false ? $maxCampingPersons : 'No info';} ?> ` because if user will chose for no camping, the result will be 0-1, so -1.

Comment: I managed to do it with a new table in database, a lot of code again. Thanks for your answers :D